# How do prevent multiple submits in a web part

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a visual web part that has an update panel that has a button that performs an action.  I want to prevent users from hitting that button more than once.

The solutions I found use javascript to disable the button then do the postback.

The problem with this that I am having is that my buttonclick method is getting called 2 times since it seems to go to Page_Load 2 times.

Here is my code.  First the button and javascript then the Page_Load method.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableButton() {
        document.getElementById('<%= BetOnCar.ClientID %>').disabled = "disabled";
        __doPostBack('<%= BetOnCar.ClientID %>', ''); 

    } 
</script> 

<asp:Button ID="BetOnCar" runat="server" Text="Bet" OnClientClick="DisableButton();" onclick="BetOnCar_Click" Enabled="false" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string controlName = this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
        if (BetOnCar.ClientID == this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"])
        {
            BetOnCar_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

I'm hoping that I am doing this type of thing in the wrong location because it seems like page_load gets hit more often than I expected.

Comment: Does this actually find your button: document.getElementById('<%= BetOnCar.ClientID %>')

Comment: It does get the button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have add ***return false;*** in the javascript function DisableButton() OR use Jquery [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) .

As the default button click is also firing

Answer (score 0):

You'll get two post backs since you're adding a __doPostBack() in your DisableButton() function. Try to remove that one.

Comment: I tried that and I get only one postback but there is no way to know what to call from this as this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] is "" and it still won't directly go to the button click method